# Angular2 Route Access denied logic

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I'm trying to put access checks for routes and display access denied page instead of actual page. From the  example below we can alert access denied on route click . I would prefer to navigate to the actual page and then show Access denied.

http://plnkr.co/edit/w1NCkGs0Tv5TjivYMdvt?p=preview

lets say url with access check is `/admin/manageusers` and component name is `ManageUserComponent` and if a user don't have access and  tries the url, it should navigate to the  route `/admin/manageusers`  but should be  showing `Access Denied in the page`.

1.One thing i can do is to use route `resolve` feature and get the value related to users access and in `ManageUserComponent` and switch the template. This approach will endup having similar  code in multiple components  associated with routes where i want to implement access logic.

2. Let all `component` where  access check needed extends another `base class` and  validate above logic , if success  then allow child component to proceed. Yet to figure out how to extend another class properly

Main goal is to preserve the accessed url with  error message in the page. And the component functions should not execute.

If you can think of approaches and options to implement, please share.

If the description is not clear please let me know, i will try to make it better.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this on the app-routing.module.ts

```
// PRIVATE ROUTES
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
},
```

then define this LoggedInGuard service

```js
// logged-in.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _authService: AuthService) { }

    canActivate() {
        // return true
        if (this._authService.isLogged()) {
            // all ok, proceed navigation to routed component
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // redirect to the homepage
            this._router.navigate(['/'], { skipLocationChange: true });
            // abort current navigation
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you out.

Comment: I was aware of `canActivate` but the  tricky thing is in `else` case its routed to `login` page not staying in same page as user accessed.

My goal is to keep same url with different component and view if possible.

Comment: @tomalex Add `skipLocationChange: true` like this: `this._router.navigate(['/'], { skipLocationChange: true })`

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement `CanActivate` logic
2. Implement guarded component and add route to it (for instance: 'denied').
3. Use `skipLocationChange` option to navigate in router

```js
@Injectable()
export class CanActivateRequestForm implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot,
    ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
        let obs = this.authService.userChange.asObservable().map(({role}) => role === Role.Admin);
        obs.subscribe(v => {
            if (!v)
                this.router.navigate(['denied'], {
                    skipLocationChange: true
                });
        });
        return obs;
    }
}
```